# How to get the client rect offsets of a window relative to the non-client rect of that window?

Tags: windows, winapi, rect

I need to get the client rect offsets of a window relative to the non-client rect of that window.

I have tried `GetClientRect` but this only gets the client rect relative to the client rect itself, meaning: `rect.left = 0`, `rect.top = 0`, `rect.right = clientWidth` and `rect.bottom = clientHeight`.

So, how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *client rect relative to the window itself* - this is what ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The client rect relative to the window itself is the one with `rect.left = 0`, `rect.top = 0`, `rect.right = clientWidth`, and `rect.bottom = clientHeight`. I don't think you properly understand what `client rect` means. Can you make it more clear what you're asking, and post the code you're using that you say doesn't work?

Comment: Use `GetWindowRect` to get the window rect, and then use `MapWindowPoints` to make the coordinates relative to the parent window.

Comment: When you call `GetClientRect`, then `rect.left` and `rect.top` are always `zero`, what about the left and top borders! I maybe call `OffsetRect` to make it relative to the window, how to calculate these left and top borders to offset the client rect with? Is it even the best technique, I just got an idea. I need the client rect relative to the window so I can call `FillRect` from `WM_NCPAINT`.

Comment: If you want the offsets of the start of your Window's client area relative to the non-client area, pass a POINT structure initialized to zeroes to the ClientToScreen() providing the screen coordinates of the client area start.  Then subtract *that* point from the upper left and/or lower right points of the result of GetWindowRect().  This gives you the offsets of your non-client area.  I.e. the upper left point becomes how many pixels *in* from the upper left corner of the window the client area begins.  The lower right becomes how many pixels until your client area ends.

Comment: @byteptr `If you want the offsets of the start of your Window's client area relative to the non-client area.` That is exactly what i want i just didn't know how to formulate the question properly. Your solution is somehow complicated, but I will try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want the non-client offsets from the edges of the Window into the client rectangle.  That is, the left and top internal leading pixels along with the right and bottom trailing pixels.  Within these offsets (sizes), you could have the title bar, menu bar and edges that adorn your client rectangle if you were doing this for a top-level window such as a dialog.  Windows doesn't calculate this for you, but it provides everything you need to calculate it yourself.  Here is some sample code that you might use to perform this calculation from a given window handle:

```
RECT rcNonCli = {0,0,0,0}; //calculate non-client offsets here
RECT rcWin = {0,0,0,0};
RECT rcClient = {0,0};
POINT ptClient = {0,0};
if (GetWindowRect(hwnd,&rcWin) && GetClientRect(hwnd,&rcClient) && ClientToScreen(hwnd,&ptClient))
{
    rcNonCli.left = ptClient.x - rcWin.left;
    rcNonCli.top = ptClient.y - rcWin.top;
    rcNonCli.right = rcWin.right - ptClient.x - rcClient.right;
    rcNonCli.bottom = rcWin.bottom - ptClient.y - rcClient.bottom;

    printf("nonclient offsets={%d,%d,%d,%d}\n",rcNonCli.left,rcNonCli.top,rcNonCli.right,rcNonCli.bottom);
}
```

EXPLANATION:
ClientToScreen() gives us the beginning coordinate of the client area providing the top and left offsets.  Once we know this, we can subtract from the complete Window size (from GetWindowRect()), the client size (from GetClientRect()) and the non-client top and left offsets to give us what remains which would be the bottom and right offsets.

Comment: Glad this works @Tomay. As you said in a previous comment, you weren't sure how to word the question originally.  Knowing what you know now, it might be a good idea to edit the question to be clearer so as to help others that come across this page. At a minimum, I think you should specify "non-client" area somewhere as this is the Microsoft term for what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

As Jonathan Potter commented, I recommend you to use [MapWindowPoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mapwindowpoints).

You can pass the rect obtained by [GetClientRect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getclientrect) into [MapWindowPoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mapwindowpoints), and set the `cPoints` parameter to `2`, to get the coordinates relative to the window you want.

Here is the sample:

```
#include <Windows.h>
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
    static TCHAR szAppName[] = TEXT("hello windows");
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG msg;
    WNDCLASS wndclass;
    wndclass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wndclass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wndclass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wndclass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wndclass.hInstance = hInstance;
    wndclass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndclass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wndclass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wndclass.lpszClassName = szAppName;
    if (!RegisterClass(&wndclass))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("This program requires Windows NT!"), szAppName, MB_ICONERROR);
    }

    hwnd = CreateWindow(szAppName,
        TEXT("the hello program"),
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, iCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    while (GetMessageW(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessageW(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HDC hdc;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    RECT rect;
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);
        DrawTextW(hdc, (L"Hello,Windows"), -1, &rect, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);
        MapWindowPoints(hwnd, HWND_DESKTOP, (LPPOINT)&rect, 2);
        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        return 0;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

You can observe the result of rect after calling the [`MapWindowPoints`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mapwindowpoints). It converts the original coordinates to the coordinates relative to the desktop.